# Convergence implies boundness of a sequence but an example confuses me!

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

given the following sequence

$$
p_{n} = \frac{1}{n-1}
$$

I am tempted to say that for n=1 the sequence assumes an infinite (and thus unbounded) value but still the sequence converges to zero as n increases.
I am of course wrong because this contradicts theorem 3.2c of Baby Rudin which states that "if a sequence is convergent in a metric space then it's bounded". What am I missing? Maybe 1/0 is not a mathematical defined value?
I would be greatly thankful for an answer.

Erma

Comment: For $n=1$, $p_n$ is not defined. or if you say that one of the sequence terms is infinite, that term is certainly not a number, and so the sequence is not  a sequence of numbers

Comment: What is the set of values the index is taking?  Is $n=1$ actually in the set of such values?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks.

Comment: @EricTowers Yes I am considering n=1,2,3,... Sorry for being not precise about that.

Answer (score -1):

Single values for which $p_n$ is not defined are not relevant when we take the limit as $n\to \infty$ what matters is that $p_n$ is eventually a well defined expression.

For example

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1{\sqrt{n^2-1\,000\,n-1\,000\,000}}$$

is not well defined for a finite number of values but the limit is equal to $0$ since eventually the expression inside the square root becomes positive and tends to $\infty$.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks.

Comment: @erma You are welcome! Bye